# Msc binary file format

Tags: windows, mmc

I manage a lot of environments, that potentially have a number of machines - I'm looking to create a push  button that creates and opens an MSC file for an environment - that is, adds a snap in for the services, and the computer management, for each server in the environment.

Creating the xml is no problem at all - however, for the services snap in, the name of the server is hidden somewhere inside a magic text encoded binary blob.   Given I know the server name, anyone know how I create the binary data?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in the xml, but you could start your mmc with the `/computer=computername ` parameter to target a specific computer

Comment: Thanks - I actually did that and got that working - and it does work for services and computer management, but doesn't for component services :(  However, it only works for one server at a time - I can't create a console with all the servers in an environment this way.